# Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on <file>

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems, xattr, ioctl

I am unable to set or view file attributes using lsattr and chattr commands on Reiser File System. Following result is observed:

```
chattr +i Temp.txt
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on Temp.txt

lsattr Temp.txt
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on Temp.txt
```

Is there a way to get file attributes with ReiserFS or how should I access file attributes on ReiserFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [a mailing list question from 2003](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2003/08/msg02343.html), Reiserfs doesn't support `chattr`.  Granted that was a long time ago, but given your error above, it seems likely that it still doesn't.